# USB disk doesn't show up in macOS Sierra, but it does in Recovery Mode

Tags: hard-drive, usb, disk-utility, macos

I've got a 2TB Toshiba USB drive which I have been using for my Time Machine backups. Since a few days this disk no longer shows up when I connect it. Already tried completely shutting everything down and rebooting, no difference.

- When running Disk Utility, it's not there.
- When running `diskutil list`, it's not there.
- I can't mount it (there's no volume or anything to mount).
- I tried both USB ports, with the same cable I always use (it has always worked fine on both USB ports before).
- When looking in System Information, either in the Store or USB section, it's not there.
- I have [reset the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (previously PRAM) as well as the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).
- I checked if `fsck` might be running while it's seemingly busy, but that's not the case. I also checked if VirtualBox was trying to filter the USB drive, also not the case (actually, VirtualBox is not running at all).
  (I found these two suggestions in a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183003/usb-drive-will-not-mount-not-listed-in-disk-utilities-but-found-in-system-prof))
- It's not an NTFS drive.

However, when I reboot into [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and look in the Disk Utility there, it *does* show up!

Also, when I connect the USB drive in OS X, it starts buzzing and spinning i.e. making the usual sounds as if it's working normally. Goes on like that for about half a minute and then stops.

Any advice? I'm convinced that 'something' was changed to my system configuration that's causing the drive not to show up, but I can't seem to find out what.

Would it be wise or safe to start in Recovery Mode again, and do a First Aid / Disk Repair from there? (I would *really* prefer if the data on this drive doesn't get messed up)

Comment: I had a similar problem with an external USB 3.0 hard drive and my new MacBook Pro. Under regular operation it wasn't visible at all but in recovery mode it was. I figured the drive had gotten corrupted, perhaps from being disconnected from the computer at an inopportune time. It was under warranty, so I erased it and returned it to the shop. Life is too short for flakey drives.

Comment: @MichaelStern Fully agree, but if there's a way to get some data off this drive before replacing it, it would save me quite some hassle. I'm especially wondering because the drive *does* show up normally in Disk Utility when booting in Recovery Mode (with ⌘+R). This really makes me doubt if the disk is flakey, or if something is messed up in my macOS.