# 1TB NTFS Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex external HD won't mount on Mac Mini

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, mac-mini, ntfs

I've been using my 2.5" 1TB external GoFlex HD on my Mac and it has been running pretty fine until last week when it stopped mounting out of the blue.

BTW It is NTFS-formatted because from time to time I freelance on companies where there's Windows and I can't have it Mac-formatted. The thing is that I can hear the noise it usually makes but it seems not enough power goes through or something power-related just stopped working.

I tried almost everything there is, Mac won't list it with `diskutil list` on terminal. I even read this thread the exact same problem as mine. Here's the System Profiler and Console Log when I plug the HD in

```
  Product ID:   0x5021
  Vendor ID:    0x0bc2  (Seagate LLC)
  Version:  1.48
  Serial Number:    NA0CC59W
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Seagate
  Location ID:  0x14700000 / 15
  Current Available (mA):   1000
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

6/6/17 11:47:45.000 kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 0x00000000 0xbc2 0x5021 0x148, 2
```

I basically found a thread with the exact same problem:

[USB Drive Will Not Mount, Not Listed in Disk Utilities, but Found In System Profiler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183003/usb-drive-will-not-mount-not-listed-in-disk-utilities-but-found-in-system-prof/223537#223537?newreg=58769793c3a54fa0bb49bdee756a2400)

But one of the answers refers to stop the "fsck_hfs" process on the Activity Monitor, but there's no such process on mine maybe because it's not HFS.

Any ideas before shave all my head in dispair?

My specs: Mac mini (Late 2014), 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5 running El Capitán

Comment: Does it work on a different machine?

Comment: Tested on a iMac and a Macbook with Windows 7. On Windows it sorta mounts but it fails to install the driver.

Comment: Win7 via Bootcamp?  If that's the case, then your drive or your enclosure is failing.  Especially so, if it "sorta" mounts on Win7

Comment: My theory is that there's not enough energy for the Mac to mount the HD because the System Profiler identifies there's something connected but fails to detect it. Maybe getting a new casing/enclosure then?

Comment: I would be willing to bet it's the enclosure.  [Open the enclosure](https://youtu.be/pP9D-Dbat9I), remote the drive and connect it with a [USB to SATA adapter](http://radnex.us/USB-30-SATA-Adapter).  Your enclosure may be toast, but at least you can get to your data.

Comment: Even with a different enclosure it won't mount. So I think I'm f*cked :(