# After disabling auto mount, can I show connected but not mounted drives in Finder sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder, external-disk, mount, automount

I have an external hard drive connected to my cinema display. I don't use the hard drive every time I connect my laptop to the display. However, I forget to unmount it almost every time I disconnect my laptop.

To avid incorrect disconnecting I disabled automounting in `fstab` as described here: [How to Disable USB Auto-mount](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120782/how-to-disable-usb-auto-mount)

Now it's hard to mount the drive as I have to go to DiskUtility. Is it possible to see the connection but not mounted hard drives in the Finder sidebar and have them mounted when the sidebar entry is selected? (the same way it works with the things shared on network)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, no **Finder** does not offer that *preference* or *option*, however there is a workaround.

I have a similar situation and I use an **AppleScript** *script* saved as an *application* that mounts the unmounted target volume when I want, without having to go into **Disk Utility** to do it.

I have this app on the **Toolbar** in **Finder**, with the same icon as shown on the drive, so it's easy to just click it. It could be placed on the **Dock** or **Desktop**, etc. At times I access it from **Spotlight** too. Lots of options, even using the *code* in an **Automator** *Service workflow* and assigning it a keyboard shortcut if you want.

```
set theVolumeName to "TOSHIBA EXT"
try
    do shell script "diskutil mount $(diskutil list | awk '/" & theVolumeName & "/{print $NF}')"
on error eStr number eNum
    if eNum is 1 then
        display dialog "The disk containing the\"" & theVolumeName & "\" volume is not available." buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Check Disk Connection & Power Status" with icon 0
    else
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Error Status" with icon 0
    end if
end try
```

Notes:

- Change `set theVolumeName to "TOSHIBA EXT"` so `"TOSHIBA EXT"` is the name of the target mounted volume.
- This script assumes there is and will only be one volume with the target name. If not, then the `awk` *command* will need to be modified to accommodate.

---

Understanding what the `do shell script` *command* is doing:

```
do shell script "diskutil mount $(diskutil list | awk '/" & theVolumeName & "/{print $NF}')"
```

- `do shell script` - Executes a shell script using the `sh` shell.
- `diskutil mount device` - Mount a single volume.
- `$(...)` - Command Substitution. - Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name. In this case it will be *device* in: `diskutil mount device`
- `diskutil list` - List disks. If no argument is given, then all disks and all of their partitions are listed.
- `|` - Pipe the output of the previous *command* to the next *command*.
- `awk '/" & theVolumeName & "/{print $NF}'` - The example will be:
   `awk '/TOSHIBA EXT/{print $NF}'`

  - `awk` - Pattern-directed scanning and processing language.
  - `/TOSHIBA EXT/` - Search pattern. Outputs the record (line) containing the search pattern.
    In this example it matched:
            `1:               Windows_NTFS TOSHIBA EXT             2.0 TB     disk1s1`
  - `{print $NF}` - Prints the last field of the record. Which printed: `disk1s1`

The following is example output in Terminal:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            750.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS TOSHIBA EXT             2.0 TB     disk1s1
$ diskutil list | awk '/TOSHIBA EXT/{print $NF}'
disk1s1
$ diskutil mount $(diskutil list | awk '/TOSHIBA EXT/{print $NF}')
Volume TOSHIBA EXT on disk1s1 mounted
$
```

So it finds the *device* for the `diskutil mount device` *command* regardless of how many disks are attached to the system.

Answer (score -1):

No, but you could use Terminal:
diskutil list
is the command.